# Check for the response login?login_error=t in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

We are using AngularJS and Spring Security for developing authentication. For certain reasons, the frontend isn't receiving a response from the baclend when a user logs in. The backend handles the redirect.

However we run the issue of not knowing if the user has entered in incorrect details. If the user enters in incorrect credentials, the only thing to indicate that the login details is `login?login_error=t` returned from Spring Security. Check snippet from chrome network tab.

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way to access all responses, or at least the value of the request? So I can check if `login?login_error=t` was returned?

Comment: *The backend handles the redirect.* That's wrong. Your browser handles the redirect.

Comment: Okay. Noted, do you have a solution though?